# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison Python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function to print some sort of permutations in python.
However I get maximum depth error for some reason.

```
def perm(chars, k, word):
   if k == 0:
      print(word)
   for char in chars:
      perm(chars, k - 1, char + word)


perm(['1','2'], 2, '')
```

Anyone has any idea what the error is?

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a [base case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_case_(recursion)), causing your call stack to [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow). Add a base case by making the `for` loop (the recursive case) conditional:

```
def perm(chars, k, word):
   if k == 0:
       print(word)
   else:
       for char in chars:
           perm(chars, k - 1, char + word)


perm(['1','2'], 2, '')
```

Output:

```
11
21
12
22
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/HilariousAquamarineSpools)

Comment: yeah apparently i was just missing that else :)

Comment: Just to piggyback- OP, maximum recursion depth is almost always a telltale sign of an infinite loop. A common error that leads to infinite loops is incorrect base cases, as we have seen here